# Network Analysis using textnets - ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed

Tags: python, nlp, network-analysis

I am trying to perform network analysis on some text data after I did some sentiment analysis on it. I am using `textnets` documentation for reference. I am getting the above mentioned error after running the following line:

```
t = tn.Textnet(corpus.tokenized())
```

Here is my full Code:

```
import textnets as tn
tn.params["seed"] = 42

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\User\Downloads\archive\nltk_split.csv")
df.head()

df.drop(['Unnamed: 0.2', 'Unnamed: 0.1', 'Unnamed: 0', 'Unnamed: 15', 'Unnamed: 16', 'id', 'favorite_count', 'created_at', 'retweet_count', 'coordinates', 'score', 'neg', 'neu', 'pos', 'compound','created_at_date'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.head()

corpus = tn.Corpus.from_df(df, doc_col='text')
t = tn.Textnet(corpus.tokenized())
t.plot(label_nodes=True,
       show_clusters=True)
```

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_19036\2509364554.py in <module>
----> 1 t = tn.Textnet(corpus.tokenized())

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\textnets\network.py in __init__(self, data, min_docs, connected, remove_weak_edges, doc_attrs)
    353             self._matrix = data
    354         elif isinstance(data, (TidyText, pd.DataFrame)):
--> 355             self._matrix = _im_from_tidy_text(data, min_docs)
    356         if remove_weak_edges:
    357             pairs: pd.Series = self._matrix.stack()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\textnets\network.py in _im_from_tidy_text(tidy_text, min_docs)
    812         .set_index("label")
    813     )
--> 814     im = tt[tt["keep"]].pivot(values="term_weight", columns="term").fillna(0)
    815     return IncidenceMatrix(im)
    816 

E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in pivot(self, index, columns, values)
   7883         from pandas.core.reshape.pivot import pivot
   7884 
-> 7885         return pivot(self, index=index, columns=columns, values=values)
   7886 
   7887     _shared_docs[

E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py in pivot(data, index, columns, values)
    518         else:
    519             indexed = data._constructor_sliced(data[values]._values, index=multiindex)
--> 520     return indexed.unstack(columns_listlike)
    521 
    522 

E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in unstack(self, level, fill_value)
   4155         from pandas.core.reshape.reshape import unstack
   4156 
-> 4157         return unstack(self, level, fill_value)
   4158 
   4159     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py in unstack(obj, level, fill_value)
    489         if is_1d_only_ea_dtype(obj.dtype):
    490             return _unstack_extension_series(obj, level, fill_value)
--> 491         unstacker = _Unstacker(
    492             obj.index, level=level, constructor=obj._constructor_expanddim
    493         )

E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py in __init__(self, index, level, constructor)
    138             )
    139 
--> 140         self._make_selectors()
    141 
    142     @cache_readonly

E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py in _make_selectors(self)
    186 
    187         selector = self.sorted_labels[-1] + stride * comp_index + self.lift
--> 188         mask = np.zeros(np.prod(self.full_shape), dtype=bool)
    189         mask.put(selector, True)
    190 

ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

Answer (score 0):

Your corpus is too large, causing `pandas` (which powers `textnets`) to run out of memory during the pivot operation.

I suggest filing a bug report at https://github.com/jboynyc/textnets/issues with some details about the size of your dataset.

Comment: It does not answer question. you can add it as comment.